# Overloading class properties based on constructor arguments in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In our codebase we use a navigator and builder patterns pretty extensively to abstract away assembling hierarchical objects. At the heart of this is a `Navigator` class which we use to traverse different classes. I'm currently attempting to migrate this to typescript but am struggling to type it to leverage the power of typescript.

I think the core of my problem is that I can't use `this` as the default value for a generic on a class e.g. `class Something<T = this>`, or that I can't overload the class to somehow conditionally set the types of class properties. Can you provide any insights into how I might be able to type the `Navigator` (and builder classes) below?

```js
// I guess what I'd like to do is
// class Navigator<BackT = this> but that's not allowed
class Navigator<BackT> {
  // It's this 'back' type I'll like to define more specifically
  // i.e. if back is passed to the constructor then it should be 'BackT'
  //      if back is not passed to the constructor or is undefined, it 
  //      should be 'this'
  back: BackT | this; 

  constructor(back?: BackT)  {
    this.back = back || this;
  }
}

class Builder1<BackT> extends Navigator<BackT> {
  builder1DoSomething() {
    // Do some work here
    return this;
  }
}

class Builder2<BackT> extends Navigator<BackT> {
  withBuilder1() {
    return new Builder1(this);

    // Also tried the following, but I got the same error:
    // return new Builder1<this>(this);
  }

  builder2DoSomething() {
    // Do some work here
    return this;
  }
}

// This is fine
new Builder1().builder1DoSomething().builder1DoSomething();

new Builder2()
  .withBuilder1()
  .builder1DoSomething()
  // I get an error here becuase my types are not specific enough to
  // let the complier know 'back' has taken me out of 'Builder1' and
  // back to 'Builder2'
  .back.builder2DoSomething();
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-Sl2JAoPdQBhodNDeJAcCdHAODAeJQbi4qC4AA6IKfgi1ahC7jgkTMcJamGBQNBUaijsBEScGSgcW7b0jTUBkUwc3BNMhcEBHgqAwChoT1ah1WoGVQFwa1ThmIDpzsHp2AAu84IQ9FcD7UJKxtT0rjLYcGyAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional type on the `back` field to type it as `this` if no type argument was supplied to the class. We will use the `void` type as the default to signal the absence of a type argument:

```
class MyNavigator<BackT = void> {
  back: BackT extends void ? this : BackT; // Conditional type 

  constructor(back?: BackT)  {
    this.back = (back || this) as any;
  }
}

class Builder1<BackT = void> extends MyNavigator<BackT> {
  builder1DoSomething() {
    return this;
  }
}

class Builder2<BackT = void> extends MyNavigator<BackT> {
  withBuilder1() {
    return new Builder1(this);
  }
  builder2DoSomething() {
    return this;
  }
}

new Builder2()
  .withBuilder1()
  .builder1DoSomething()
  // ok now
  .back.builder2DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to create a special variant of every class which works like your option with no constructor parameter. So have a special `SelfNavigator`, `SelfBuilder1` etc. extending their corresponding classes, and having no generic types themselves.

```
class MyNavigator<BackT> {
  back: BackT;

  constructor(back: BackT) {
    this.back = back;
  }
}

class SelfMyNavigator extends MyNavigator<SelfMyNavigator> {}

class Builder1<BackT> extends MyNavigator<BackT> {
  builder1DoSomething() {
    // Do some work here
    return this;
  }
}

class SelfBuilder1 extends Builder1<SelfBuilder1> {
  constructor() {
    super((null as unknown) as SelfBuilder1);
    this.back = this;
  }
}

class Builder2<BackT> extends MyNavigator<BackT> {
  withBuilder1() {
    return new Builder1(this);
  }
  builder2DoSomething() {
    // Do some work here
    return this;
  }
}

class SelfBuilder2 extends Builder2<SelfBuilder2> {
  constructor() {
    super((null as unknown) as SelfBuilder2);
    this.back = this;
  }
}

// This is fine
new SelfBuilder1().builder1DoSomething().builder1DoSomething();

new SelfBuilder2()
  .withBuilder1()
  .builder1DoSomething()
  .back.builder2DoSomething();
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-C4VAuBKyAYJiEbVggEocCQOEcGMpgwFAaBUNQElgEQMkGJQPJ-GKpDHKAIHRrg1RkLgyIKlgGAULi9bUBW1B9KAuB8UFGAzI5dRIjQcVnvauCCaEZE3iJVEjkAA)

Note that you cannot call `super(this)` so the ugly casts are used. There are different ways to avoid this, to make the code nicer, e.g. convert everything to a system of interfaces and abstract classes so that the field `back` is not in the superclass, but rather a superinterface. Or make it a getter and return `this` if not set, although this will still need some casts.