# Typescript different class property types depending on arguments

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types

I have a `User` class, which I instantiate with an object, which may be `null` if the user is not authenticated. I would like to make different property types depending on its state. This is what I tried:

```js
// `IUser` is an interface with user properties like `id`, `email`, etc.
class User<T extends IUser | null> implements IUser {
  id: T extends null ? null : string
  email: T extends null ? null : string
  age: T extends null ? null : number
  // ...

  authenticated: T extends null ? false : true

  constructor(user: T) {
    if(user === null) {
      this.authenticated = false
      this.id = this.email = this.age = null
    } else {
      this.authenticated = true
      ;({
        id: this.id,
        email: this.email,
        age: this.age,
      } = user)
    }
  }
}
```

But this solution causes an error `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T extends null ? false : true'` when setting the `authenticated` field, and a bunch of errors like `property 'email' doesn't exist on type 'IUser | null'` in the `else` clause. My issue is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887863/overloading-class-properties-based-on-constructor-arguments-in-typescript), where the response suggested to do `this.authenticated = true as any`. In fact, this does remove one error, but the whole point of this headache is to be able to write

```js
if(user.authenticated) {
  // email is certainly not null
  const { email } = user 
}
```

which doesn't work with this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you would like the `User` type to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) like `{authenticated: true, age: number, email: string, ...} | {authenticated: false, age: null, email: null, ...}`.  Unfortunately, `class` and `interface` types cannot themselves be unions, so there's no simple way to represent this.

Your attempt with conditional types would only possibly work from the outside of the class implementation, and then only if your `user` is of type `User<IUser> | User<null>`, which becomes a discriminated union.  But the type `User<IUser | null>` is not equivalent to that.  And furthermore it doesn't work *inside* the class implementation, where the type parameter `T` is unspecified, because the compiler doesn't do control-flow type analysis on generic types'; see [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085). So we should find a different way to represent this.

---

By far the most straightforward way is to make `User` *have* a possible-`IUser`, and not *be* a possible-`IUser`.  This principle of "having" instead of "being" is known as [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  And instead of checking some other property named `unauthenticated`, you'd only have to check the property of possible-`IUser` type. Here it is:

```
class User {
  constructor(public user: IUser | null) {}
}

const u = new User(Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : 
  { id: "alice", email: "alice@example.com", age: 30 });
if (u.user) {
  console.log(u.user.id.toUpperCase());
}
```

---

If you really want to check an `authenticated` property to distinguish between the presence and absence of an `IUser`, you can still do it by making the `user` property a discriminated union like this:

```
// the discriminated type from above, written out programmatically
type PossibleUser = (IUser & { authenticated: true }) |
  ({ [K in keyof IUser]: null } & { authenticated: false });

// a default unauthenticated user
const nobody: { [K in keyof IUser]: null } = { age: null, email: null, id: null };

class User {
  user: PossibleUser;
  constructor(user: IUser | null) {
    this.user = user ? { authenticated: true, ...user } : { authenticated: false, ...nobody };
  }
}

const u = new User(Math.random() < 0.5 ? null :
  { id: "alice", email: "alice@example.com", age: 30 });
if (u.user.authenticated) {
  console.log(u.user.id.toUpperCase());
}
```

but the extra complexity here might not be worth the benefit.

---

If you really need the `User` class to *be* a possible-`IUser`, then you have other options.  The normal way of getting union types with classes would be to use inheritance; have an abstract `BaseUser` class which captures behavior common to both authenticated and unauthenticated users, like this:

```
type WideUser = { [K in keyof IUser]: IUser[K] | null };
abstract class BaseUser implements WideUser {
  id: string | null = null;
  email: string | null = null;
  age: number | null = null;
  abstract readonly authenticated: boolean;
  commonMethod() {

  }
}
```

And then make two subclasses, `AuthenticatedUser` and `UnauthenticatedUser` which specialize the behavior for the different types:

```
class AuthenticatedUser extends BaseUser implements IUser {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  age: number;
  readonly authenticated = true;
  constructor(user: IUser) {
    super();
    ({
      id: this.id,
      email: this.email,
      age: this.age,
    } = user)
  }
}

type IUnauthenticatedUser = { [K in keyof IUser]: null };
class UnauthenticatedUser extends BaseUser implements IUnauthenticatedUser {
  id = null;
  email = null;
  age = null;
  readonly authenticated = false;
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Now instead of having a single class constructor you have two, so your `User` type would be a union, and to get a new one you might use a function instead of a class constructor:

```
type User = AuthenticatedUser | UnauthenticatedUser;
function newUser(possibleUser: IUser | null): User {
  return (possibleUser ? new AuthenticatedUser(possibleUser) : new UnauthenticatedUser());
}
```

And it has the expected behavior:

```
const u = newUser(Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : 
  { id: "alice", email: "alice@example.com", age: 30 });
if (u.authenticated) {
  console.log(u.id.toUpperCase());
}
```

---

Finally, if you absolutely must have a single class corresponding to your `User` union, you can do it by making a class implement a wider non-union type, and then [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that the constructor for that class makes union instances.  It's not very type safe inside the class implementation, but it should work as well outside.  Here's the implementation:

```
class _User implements WideUser {
  id: string | null
  email: string | null
  age: number | null
  authenticated: boolean;
  constructor(user: IUser | null) {
    if (user === null) {
      this.authenticated = false
      this.id = this.email = this.age = null
    } else {
      this.authenticated = true;
      ({
        id: this.id,
        email: this.email,
        age: this.age,
      } = user)
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I named it `_User` so that the name `User` is available for the following type and constructor definitions:

```
// discriminated union type, named PossibleUser before
type User = (IUser & { authenticated: true }) | 
  ({ [K in keyof IUser]: null } & { authenticated: false });
const User = _User as new (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof _User>) => User;
```

And now this works as you might have expected, using `new User()`:

```
const u = new User(Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : 
  { id: "alice", email: "alice@example.com", age: 30 });
if (u.authenticated) {
  console.log(u.id.toUpperCase());
}
```

---

Okay, done.  It's up to you which way to go here.  Personally I'd recommend the simplest solution, which requires some refactoring but is the most TypeScript-friendly way forward.

[Playground Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO1kG8CwAUMssACYBcymYUoA5gNxEkQC2cwANlTXSExbI49CFRABXNgCNozQgF8iREHDYRMAB0QoAwgHs2m-ZmBhg+kAHkAbtFQgAFtDNwQSAIx5lxZAi5wmJjIWDgEviQIlnwSCGD6UAAUmhLSXMAIyBLYUFQYOcgAPsiSXFwAlN4RyEq+tUJRIDRZyAC8JRAA7iE5iQCycGCOAHRQbmSGiZUAPMgADMMArMgA-CUSZchUuKSUyABEcOlI+wA0yOycPAdHGRAAAhAAHmqaXBDDUWxnwqJUAMxzGrleQkYAwZCJCTDbLQSrhEiRaL6d7DLj6ehQmE5YbkYbxdCaTTQXSBCBTEFCeqKHwqNQabRIZAGIwmMwWax2KAOZx0MBuJAAJiqJAA9KLkEMUGRgJgEHQ2KBBhAyJKAJ7E5AwKCGYTSfR2c6dPmQEDIfQSMDITQ6+hjNgccwII5cNVCMAalAABRMpjSEFCUDakPyOAAZHhhJbnOAMsq9rQJCgFJVCkISIkdgBtADSpDNAGsIGr9BDQ1AALriDZcGrICM7ODRiCx52QPbwLjYYHyITi4TIMgQeAbK0SVTN1vxrI5BrRK0gfT6shq7bIXP55BFktlwNV9abBTBxt-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-QUHPkDNZRI6NtarcH62iEHXA47t+0E79vvBjREBk1xFNgSz9PUEzAmswhKvUiQ6soHryA-drbb2wUxToN7RN+3IQgwOOcQch0nSBskvr-u8ga00Gy0VFQnUKTtYASFAZrd3+AEFLJfEV7bVeN0kxiz33itbB3IT139XflPnquEO9IHcYNXRdwMQyjOMkwzPMSwYXJa5KZpdxqaHVDv0g2mvHphgDKnhMimIC5ksSEz+g5aoTlUSuSxJ5fQhJmakmwH5KkPhqSqGCoyFAABlBg7xdBWy+kEaA7YqixU1O1ZKqFIwbgytubK5Z9zlgKv1aaFtnxW2QAAfXBu7SGYA2pJVHtUHqCN6AcLKApQWvUBDSK4JHIykgsaKPWonFeZ19AXRAGnUCVMILQAHoo6BctwHoVaFYs8Zi5ZC2spo6c7QU780RFLYWgd2juJFqHEmSFhaGWjq4o8EAuzRVccXfxDjK5OMlBTVOETIQc3MQmKJvNEmsC-vY0WGTfhGW8TLRJR4FZwmCcrDBvgS78SDO0RIMMGxHWXlROJSZgRFUzAbTcTCTbQDNpw+smFHG4S1EcbsoC5xcWqcGfhBRAg70SERayUB6CYCoAYdOlMEhejgPae60BMDTBLtlGZ0AAB8lRWinOqU+TizQJA8T4lfISt9RL30ko-GSxVX57B-qpC8WTfl-2ap8QB5wMYgKPhY6JTT7Kw1gS5DECCyD4iQd5KAqDySH38rSRQQA)